# How to use removeListener in node.js/socket.io to prevent multiple triggered function

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, p5.js

I'm having a problem about socket.io/node.js. I'm emitting client to server and vice versa and it triggering my function more than one even though I'm just triggering it once. So here's my code

Client side;

```
for (var x = circles.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    if (circle.eat(circles[x])) {
        position = {
             x: circles[x].position.x,
             y: circles[x].position.y,
             r: circles[x].position.r,
             index: x
        };
        circles.splice(x, 1);
        socket.emit('eat', position); //Here's the emit to server.
   }
}
```

Server Side;

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

socket.on('eat',
    function(data){
    circlePosition.splice(data.index, 1);
    counter++;
    eventEmitter.removeListener('eat', this); //Removing this listener but planning to use it again by adding it again using addListener
});
```

I already tried to compare the incoming datas to the recently sent datas by an if else to avoid duplication of datas even it will be triggered multiple times but still the problem occur, and if I use that method the precision of data will be a problem. So I'm trying to use a removeListener and addListener but the the error is;

[image]

How to get rid of this?

**EDIT**

I've tried to make the **listen** variable make true again once it is emitted from client to server, here's the code

Client Side:

```
for (var x = circles.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    if (circle.eat(circles[x])) {
        position = {
            x: circles[x].position.x,
            y: circles[x].position.y,
            r: circles[x].position.r,
            index: x,
                        listen: false   //Condition to if else in server side
        };
        circles.splice(x, 1);
        socket.emit('eat', position); //Here's the emit to server.
    }
}
```

Server Side:

```
socket.on('eat', eatFunction);

function eatFunction(data){
    if(!data.listen){   //listen variable used inside the if else block
        circlePosition.splice(data.index, 1);
        counter++;
        data.listen = null;
        console.log(data.listen + " " + counter); //to see if the listen becomes null and the counter to see how many times it triggers
        eventEmitter.removeAllListeners('eat', eatFunction);
    }
}
```

I think the problem is the Client side because it sends more than it should, not the receiving.

Comment: The `this` pointer points to the event emitter. See the docs here: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener

There's also an example in the docs of removing a listener.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli is this the reason why I'm having this error? Should I write the function outside the socket.on argument so I can properly call the function? Is there any equivalent of **this** pointer so i can call the function within there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple trigger socket.emit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477203/multiple-trigger-socket-emit)

Comment: Please stop posting multiple copies of [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477203/multiple-trigger-socket-emit).

Comment: @KevinWorkman I'm trimming and summarizing the post because I think the original post was uncleared, and by the way I'm deleting the previous post so I don't cause spam or something. And I think I'm making a progress and changes every post.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate Please just edit your original question instead of posting multiple copies.

Comment: @KevinWorkman noted sir.

Comment: @KevinWorkman any thoughts about here?

Comment: @bretcopeland I've seen posts that you're commenting with the almost the same matter, any thoughts about here?

Comment: @jfriend00 any thoughts about here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
eventEmitter.removeListener('eat', this);
```

What object do you think `this` refers to here? It seems like you think it's referring to the function, but that's not the case. The `this` keyword in JavaScript can be a little tricky, but basically it's going to refer to the instance that contains the function, not the function itself.

You need to pass a reference to the function itself. It might be easier if you stop using an inline function and use a named function instead:

```
socket.on('eat', eatFunction);

function eatFunction(data){
    circlePosition.splice(data.index, 1);
    counter++;
    eventEmitter.removeListener('eat', eatFunction);
}
```

Notice that the `eatFunction()` now has a name, so you can use it as a parameter for both the `on()` and `removeListener()` functions.

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on creating JavaScript functions available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-functions).

**Edit:** If all you're trying to do is top reacting to events, why don't you just use a variable that keeps track of whether you should react to events? Something like this:

```
var listen = true;

socket.on('eat', eatFunction);

function eatFunction(data){
    if(listen){
       circlePosition.splice(data.index, 1);
       counter++;
       listen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error about listener was gone but still the bug about the multiple triggering of the function was still there. It's still triggering more than it should. I've check your site, it is great.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate Without being able to actually run your code it's hard to say, but are you sure the removal of the listener actually happens before subsequent events are fired? You might have to check the internals of the library you're using.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate I just edited my answer to include another approach you might consider.

Comment: I already tried that, it works first but on the second try how can I make the **listen** is equal to true once again? I can't put it inside the function **eatFunction** because it will be useless. I just want to prevent the multiple triggering but i don't want to remove permanently the function.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate How were you planning on adding the listener again after removing it? You would presumably set the `listen` variable to `true` the same way.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate Also note that the `eatFunction()` function is still called, so you could do something like set `listen` to `true` in an `else` block. It really depends on what you're trying to do. But my point is that adding and removing the listener feels a bit hackish, especially if something as simple as a couple if statements will accomplish your goal.

Comment: I've tried every possible ways using the if and else statement, may I mention that I used the way of comparing the both consecutive received data to each other so it would just cancel the last received. But I'm having a problem in the precision. Believe me I tried every simple ways to accomplish my goal. I wouldn't go deeper if I'd accomplished it using the simple methods.

Comment: I just edited my post and include what I've tried to make the **listen** true again.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate I honestly don't really understand what you're asking. Are you now having an issue comparing floats because of precision? That's a different question and should be in its own post, with its own [mcve]. If that's the case, a simple program using two hard-coded values would be sufficient. Don't just keep posting the same code in new questions. Try to narrow each problem down to its own MCVE, and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: I'm asking how to prevent the multiple triggered of a function. I'm just adding up somethings that I've already done so you could know what are the ways that I did to try to solve this problem.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate I understand your goal, I guess I just don't understand what trouble you're having. Using a variable and an if statement seems like a solution. You say it won't work, but I'm not sure why it won't work. You've posted code that contains a bunch of other stuff not directly related to the question, so it's hard for me to say exactly what you should do. Try creating a small example program that does what I'm suggesting, then post that if it doesn't work. That way we can both run the same code.

Comment: Hey Kevin, I already got a progress on my work, i didn't use a condition but I use **removeListener()** by this **this.removeListener('eat',eatFunction)** and not by this **eventEmitter.removeListener('eat',eatFunction)** now it works properly, it really removes the excess listener, however I'm having a problem by adding the listener again. And I think I should use the **setMaxListeners()**, should I post it as another question or should I edit this?

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate Why do you think you should use the `setMaxListeners()` function? Why are you adding the extra listener in the first place? But sure, post it as a new question. But **please** post it as a [mcve] instead of disconnected snippets or your entire project. Try to narrow this down to a small example that's just a few lines!